# ASP.NET MVC 5 Javascript: Converting list of checkbox names to string for hidden field

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying for a couple days to find a way to convert a dictionary of operating systems, that are tied to checkboxes, to a semi-colon delimited string on a hidden field, because that is how they are stored on our database.

My partial view looks like this, minus some elements that have nothing to do with this problem:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var os in Model.OperatingSystems)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OperatingSystems.First(x => x.Key == os.Key).Value, new { @style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px", @id = "osCheckbox", @name = os.Key });
        @os.Key
        <br />
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedOperatingSystems, new { @id = "SelectedOperatingSystems" })

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

And my javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#osCheckbox').click(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).checked;
        var os = $(this).name;
        var selectedOsList = document.getElementById("SelectedOperatingSystems").value;
        if (value == true)
        {
            var combined = os + ";";
            selectedOsList += combined;
        }
        else
        {
            var combined = os + ";";
            selectedOsList.replace(combined, "");
        }
        $('#SelectedOperatingSystems').val(selectedOsList);
    });
</script>
```

Right now the output shows the previously selected operating systems without change.  At least they're showing up in the model now though.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE**
Looks like the there is a problem with the code that names the checkbox as well.  The name is "Value" instead of an operating system.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to treat this an an array that is bound to your controller action and then in the controller transform it into whatever format you desire?  I feel like the translation you are doing generally would be something I do in the controller layer (or data layer, depending on what exactly the intent is)

Comment: Also,don't forget that `id` are unique...in your case `@id = "osCheckbox"` the `click` method just works for the first checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

```html
var checkVals = [];
$("input[name='osCheckbox']").each(function (i) {
     if ($(this).attr("id") != null && $(this).attr("id") != "") {
          if (this.checked) {
               checkVals[i] = $(this).attr("id") + "-true";
          }
          else {
               checkVals[i] = $(this).attr("id") + "-false";
          };
      }
 });
var names = checkVals.toString();
```

checkVals.toString() will give you all the names and indicate if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally figured it out.  Thanks for your help Dilip, with a little adjustment to the code your solution turned out to be much better than what I was trying.

First, the OS name had spaces and special characters in it, so I wrapped **@os.key** in quotation marks and put it in data.  Then changed the **id** attribute to the **name** attribute.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var os in Model.OperatingSystems)
    {
        <input name="osCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-osname="@os.Key" data-val-required="The Value field is required.">
        @os.Key
        <br />
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedOperatingSystems, new { @id = "SelectedOperatingSystems" })

    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Then I modified Dilip's solution as follows; UPDATE: not using the tostring method anymore because of issues with only one OS checked :(.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkVals = [];
    $('#submitBtn').click(function (e) {
        $("input[name='osCheckbox']").each(function (i) {
            if (this.checked) {
                checkVals[i] = $(this).data("osname");
            }
        });
        var names = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < checkVals.length; i++) {
            if (checkVals[i] != null && checkVals[i] != "") {
                names += checkVals[i]
                if (i != checkVals.length - 1) {
                    names += ";";
                }
            }
        }
        $('#SelectedOperatingSystems').val(names);
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps others.